# Succesfully Cloned and Installed pyexcel-xlsx but syntax error when importing

Tags: python, flask

Hello I'm new to web development and have been using python to make my web app. Here's my code:

```
def forecastvalues():
    import fileinput
    import csv
    from pyexcel_xlsx import get_data
    xlsxfile= "test.xlsx"
    import json

    with open(xlsxfile, "rb") as f:
    content = f.read()
    r = pe.get_book(file_type="xlsx", file_content=content, start_row=1)

    for i in records:
        columns = sheet.row[i]
         for j in columns:
             rem = sheet.column[0]
             sold1 = sheet.column[1]
             sold2  = sheet.column[2]

    return '<h1>Result: %s</h1>' % result
```

I properly installed pyexcel but when i import pyexcel it gets a syntax error, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

content = f.read() is not indented, nor its following line.

Should be:

```
with open(xlsxfile, "rb") as f:
    content = f.read()
    r = pe.get_book(file_type="xlsx", file_content=content, start_row=1)
```